# how to set and get URL parameters on a search field

Tags: jquery, json, angularjs, search, filter

How will I set the URL parameters of http://staging.api.sample.com/events.json?name=peter  and http://staging.api.sample.com/events.json?start_date_from=2015-01-01 .and set it to the search button? Like if you type the name "peter" and then if you're going to click the button the URL will load as the given URL name “Peter” then it will bring down all the list named “Peter ” on the table of events.json .the search field be like Name and Start date. If you Type the name Peter on the search field “name” then you type on the “start date” let’s say 2015-01-01. The link will combine like “***HTTP blah blah /events.json?name=peter&&start_date_from=2015-01-01***” and search if it has a match on the events.json table. It’s quite interesting right? Can anyone help me about working on it? Any suggestions? 
The code is like:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myTable">
<head>
    <title>project  43</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myTable=angular.module('myTable',[]);
  myTable.controller('tableCtrl',function($scope,$http){
  $http.get("http://staging.api.sample.com/events.json", {headers: {Authorization: 'vuNYhXbpKfH7dxkL4h1o2etBJDEiVrRdsds'}})
   .success(function(response) {
      debugger
    $scope.members=response.events;
     $scope.totals = response.paging;
  });

  });
    </script>
</head>



<body ng-controller="tableCtrl">
 <table border="5">
   <tr>
    <th>Event</th>
     <th>Account Shop</th>
     <th>Place</th>
     <th>Activity</th>
   </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="member in members">
    <td>

    {{member.Event.name}}<br>  <!--names-->
    {{member.Event.id}}<br>
    {{member.Event.date_start}}<br>   <!--Start Date-->
    {{member.Event.date_end}}<br> 


    <td>
    {{member.AccountShop.id}}<br>
    {{member.AccountShop.name}}<br>
    {{member.AccountShop.short_code}}<br>
    </td>

    <td >
    <div ng-repeat="Place in member.Place">
    {{Place.id}}<br>
    {{Place.name}}<br>
    {{Place.lk_country_code}}<br>
    </div>
    </td>

    <td>
    <div ng-repeat="Activity in member.Activity">
    {{Activity.id}}<br>
    {{Activity.short_description}}
    </div>

    </td>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can pass `ng-model` of your name and start date field to a function using `ng-click` and append it to your api url

Comment: @rahul yes sir . i tried it many times but nothing happens . since am new in angular . i dunno if my code is valid or else has a missing delimiters.

Comment: that's why i need some consultation coming from the experts in angular like you sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following :
lets say your search fields :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="name" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="date" />
<button ng-click="search(name,date)" class="blue_button" >search</button>
```

and function on scope is :

```
var myTable=angular.module('myTable',[]);
      myTable.controller('tableCtrl',function($scope,$http){
      $http.get("http://staging.api.sample.com/events.json", {headers: {Authorization: 'vuNYhXbpKfH7dxkL4h1o2etBJDEiVrRdsds'}})
       .success(function(response) {
          debugger
        $scope.members=response.events;
         $scope.totals = response.paging;
      });

    $scope.search=function(name,date){
         $http.get("http://staging.api.sample.com/events.json?name="+name+"&start_date="+date, {headers: {Authorization: 'vuNYhXbpKfH7dxkL4h1o2etBJDEiVrRdsds'}})
       .success(function(response) {

        $scope.members=response.events;
         $scope.totals = response.paging;
      });

      }
  });
```

Comment: also add check for your name and date are not null or undefined and then add it to query string.

Comment: you made me cry sir ..! it works . hope i can add you on fb sir . to ask something about angular . and to thank you sir ,@rahul

Comment: i did message you sir and add on fb. check others message . thanks!